# Telosys : How can i get database table records in template?

Tags: code-generation, telosys

I am using Telosys tools for code generation. It's very nice tool and help me a lot.

But there is one problem, that is, it provides *database schema* information and i can access in *templates* (templates are formerly velocity templates), which is good, but how can i get selected entity's **data** from database? There is no way i can find, by which i can get that selected table **data**.

Please provide solution if any, or provide alternate way to do it.

Thanking You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telosys Tools is designed to retrieve the model from the database, 
not the data stored in the tables.

But it allows to create your **own specific tooling classes** usable 
in the templates, so it's possible to create a specific Java Class to retrieve the data from the database.

There's an example of this kind of specific class in the "database-doc" bundle 
https://github.com/telosys-tools/database-doc-bundle-TT210  ( in classes folder )
To simplify the loading the simplest way is to create the class in the "default package" (no java package)

NB: 
The problem is that **the jar containing the JDBC driver 
is not accessible by the generator** class-loader, so you will have to use a **specific class-loader** and to connect directly with the JDBC driver.

Here is an **example** : https://gist.github.com/l-gu/ed0c8726807e5e8dd83a 
Don't use it as is (the connection is never closed) but it can be easily adapted.